# How to convert coordinate to lac/cid

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding

We all know that how to convert lac/cid to latitude/longitude, by use google gears like this:

```
public Location callGear(ArrayList<CellIDInfo> cellID) {
JSONObject data,current_data;
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

current_data = new JSONObject();
current_data.put(\"cell_id\", cellID.get(0).cellId);
current_data.put(\"location_area_code\", cellID.get(0).locationAreaCode);

// do something...

Location loc = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
loc.setLatitude((Double) data.get(\"latitude\"));
loc.setLongitude((Double) data.get(\"longitude\"));
return loc;
```

}

However, is it possible to do a reverse convert?
Get lac/cid from a valid coordinate?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4152570/1306419) answer. It might help.

Comment: It seems that your link is different from my problem.

Comment: My problem is: given a valid coordinate(latitude&longitude), output its corresponding lac/cid. And, can use any method, not limited to android...

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no simple way of achieving this. A given location can be served by several cells, and the cell that a mobile device selects depends on a number of factors (signal strength, for example).

The only case when you could say for sure which cell serves a given location is when you know for sure that there is one and only one cell covering that location.