# Location Area Code using android

Tags: android, location

I want to get the cell id and location area code (provided by the network operators) in my android app.

If anyone could help me out with the above.

Comment: area code means ZIP code or PIN code?

Comment: Location Area Code & Cell ID provided by the network operator. not the PIN or ZIP code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know Location Area Code and Cell ID in android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152373/how-to-know-location-area-code-and-cell-id-in-android-phone)

Comment: If my answer gives solution for you. Give upvote and accepted my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add this Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In Java Code,

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation gsmCellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

int cid = gsmCellLocation.getCid() & 0xffff;  // GSM cell id
int lac = gsmCellLocation.getLac() & 0xffff;  // GSM Location Area Code
```

I have got cell id and the location area code for GSM.

But for UMTS, getCid () returns a big number for example 33 187 589. So i add modulo operator (example: gsmCellLocation.getCid() & 0xffff).

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephony.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
        final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            lac.setText("LAC: " + location.getLac() + " CID: " + location.getCid());
        }
    }
```